# Cpanel API Database Creation with out root access

Tags: php, api, cpanel

So I'm trying to create a database/user with out root access. It's either not possible - or i've done something wrong.

Suggestions? Missing a Step?

Here is my code as of now:

```
include("xmlapi.php");   
$xmlapi = new xmlapi($db_host);    
$xmlapi->password_auth("".$cpaneluser."","".$cpanelpass."");    
$xmlapi->set_debug(1);//output actions in the error log 1 for true and 0 false  
$xmlapi->set_output('array');//set this for browser output  
//create database    
$createdb = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adddb", array($databasename));   
//create user 
$usr = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adduser", array($databaseuser, $databasepass));   
 //add user 
$addusr = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adduserdb", array("".$cpaneluser."_".$databasename."", "".$cpaneluser."_".$databaseuser."", 'all'));
```

Doing a print_r of any of the calls just tells me Array ( `[data] => Array ( [result] => 0 [reason] => Access denied` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a setting in whm only allowing ssl connections. Turned it off and worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the solution here is to do this:

```
$xmlapi->set_port( 2083 );
```

You don't need to disable SSL through WHM, that's not ideal.

Comment: Your absolutely correct.  Figured that out a few days later - but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm trying to create a database/user with out root access

Unless the user you are logging in with has permission to create new databases or users, then you will not be able to accomplish this.

This is true whether we're talking about the CPanel API or MySQL itself.

Comment: The user I'm logging in with can log into cpanel and create a database and a user.  He just doesn't have root access. Is there a different permission required?

Comment: Can the user perform *any* actions over the API?  Maybe API use itself is a permission?

Comment: There was a setting in whm only allowing ssl connections.  Turned it off and worked fine.

Comment: The joy of useless error messages!  Please post your solution as a new answer to this question and mark it accepted, so this question shows as having been fixed.